# Adding new property to class does not update database using code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

Initially, `HireDate` was not part of the class.  I called `Enabled-Migrations`, set the `AutomaticMigrations = true`, and did an `Update-Database`.  This created my Employee table with Id and Name.  When I added HireDate and ran Update-Database again, it tells me:

`No pending code-based migrations.`

Comment: how is `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` set in your DbConfigugation object ?

Comment: @tschmit007 - I have this `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 2):

Try manually adding the migration. On your package console type the following two commands

```
Add-Migration {name}
Update-Database
```

Replace {name} with your migration name

Hope this helps

Comment: Is this something new? I was following a course by Scott Allen on pluralsight and he did not do the `Add-Migration` step when he did it.

Comment: No - This just manually creates the migration instead of having them automatically created whenever the models change. Did this work for you?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried it yet.  I wanted to find the solution so I don't have to manually add the migrations.  So Add-Migration lets you keep a history of all the changes made to the db?

Comment: It creates a migration file which contains the changes to your model since the last time the database was migrated. So for instance, if you added the property date of birth to your model you would then add a migration. Once you update the database it will apply that migration to your database and the date of birth column will be added.

Comment: But if I have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled set to true, I should not have to Add Migrations, right?

Comment: True you shouldn't have to. Did you not add automatic migrations after the model has changed though? Maybe this is what the problem is